# Automapper - Map field and calculate with session variable. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Is there any way to pass a parameter to automapper when mapping a field?

I have a model property named:

```
public double Meters {get; set;}
```

I use automapper to convert those meters to KILOMETERS or MILES depending on a Session variable that is generated based on user's preference;

```
Session["Factor"] = Units.KM;
```

The problem is that when I use automapper I can do this operation

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Distance, DistanceViewModel>()
            .ForMember(a => a.Distance, exp => exp.ResolveUsing(p => p.Meters * (double)Session["Factor"]))
```

Because I can't access Session object from Automapper helper file in my MVC Project.

Did someone faced this problem? What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT:** I Tried the approach in the answer however is null.

```
public class EffortInPaceProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {

        var factor = (double)HttpContext.Current.Session["DistanceFactor"];

        Mapper.CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>()
            .ForMember(e => e.TotalMeters, exp => exp.ResolveUsing(p => p.TotalMeters * factor));
    }
}


Line 210: var factor = (double)HttpContext.Current.Session["DistanceFactor"]; //NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get it from HttpContext:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Distance, DistanceViewModel>()
       .ForMember(a => a.Distance, exp => exp.ResolveUsing(p => p.Meters * (double)HttpContext.Current.Session["Factor"]))
```

Don't forget to include System.Web namespace.

Comment: Ufuk thanks for your answer I tried your approach but the session is null. Check the edit so you can see it... Is something that I'm doing wrong? I assign the value in global.asax Session_Start

Comment: I think my problem is that I have a class to create the Mapping profiles... and is being executed before global.asax session start since the call to create the profiles are made on Application Start.